# IN array in where clause mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

In my php I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 )
```

What I did is I used `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` on my array and it turn out like:

```
["3","5"]


$array = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Now after doing this I used it in select query with IN in where clause like:

```
SELECT tablecode FROM table WHERE id IN $array
```

Now I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["3","5"]' at line 1

I followed how to use `IN` but still this happens.

How to use array in where clause with `IN`

Comment: IN needs `()` not `[]`

Comment: `json_encode` won't do what you want, and the escaping can potentially mess up your query. Instead, use prepared statements and parameter binding, ([PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ), then tweak as needed to pass in the variables for the `IN` statement. There are questions on SO that explain how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `json_encode()` either. Just make it comma separated using `implode()`.

```
$comma_separated_number = implode(', ', $array);
SELECT tablecode FROM table WHERE id IN ($comma_separated_number);
```